# "Use all my monitors for the remote session" RDP option is greyed out

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I just installed RDP 7 client on an XP SP3 PC and I do now see the checkbox for using multiple monitors... but it is greyed out.

What else do I need to do to make it selectable? Is it based on the specific client I'm connecting to? That seems unlikely since RDP wouldn't know until the connection is established.

Answer (score 2):

multiple-monitors support in Windows 7’s Remote Desktop is available only on Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Enterprise. (It is also available in Windows Server 2008 R2.) Furthermore, both the local and remote systems must be running one of the supported versions

Answer (score 0):

Open the RDP programm with notepad (right click -> open with) and add the following line under screen mode: use multimon:i:1 This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Opening an executable programm with a text editor does not sound like a good idea.